# Infinitely many primes with $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove:

**There are infinitely many primes $p$ with $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$.**

My lecture notes say this can be proven by considering the numbers $(n!)^2+1$ and using that they satisfy $(n!)^2+1\equiv 1\mod 4$.

I have two questions:

- How to conclude the claim from this fact?
- Why is the fact true?

Comment: $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo any prime factor $p$ of $(n!)^2+1$. Therefore $p\equiv1\pmod4$. If there were only finitely many such primes what would happen if $n$ were the largest of that lot?

Comment: see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof)

Comment: Why is $p\equiv 1\mod 4$ if $p$ is a prime factor of $(n!)^2+1$, @JyrkiLahtonen ?

Comment: Is the following argument OK? $p$ divides $(n!)^2+1$, hence $(n!)^2\equiv -1 \mod p$ and therefore $\left(\frac{-1}{p} \right)=1$. This implies, by Euler's lemma, that $p\equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Comment: So we found a prime $p$ which is of the form $4k+1$. Now we repeat the procedure for $n'=(p!)^2+1$. This gives us a prime $p'$ of the form $4l+1$. This prime must be bigger than $p$ because otherwise it would divide $1$.

Comment: That's the idea. Alternatively you can do a contrapositive argument. If there were only finitely many primes of this type, there would be a largest such prime...