# prove that the number of primes of the form 4k+1 is infinite

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I do not want to use modular arithmetic. I understand to assume the contrary but if someone could explain from there that would be amazing!

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof

Comment: why don't you want to use modular arithmetic?

Comment: I have been told by my professor that it is not needed