# S is the set of all numbers of the form $4n+1$ where $n \geq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let S be the set of all numbers of the form $4n+1$ where $n \geq 1$. 
Prove or Disprove:

1) There are infinitely many S-primes

(I am thinking: if $p=4n+1$ is a normal prime then p is an S-prime, using some sort of a Euclidean type argument)

2) Every number in S can be written as a finite product of S-primes

(I am thinking an induction argument)

3) Every number in S can be written $\it{uniquely}$ as a finite product of S-primes

I know that a number is an S-prime if it is not divisible by any number in S other than itself. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that by an $S$ prime you mean not a prime that is in $S$ but rather an element of $S$ that is not a non-trival product of elements of $S$, is that so?

Comment: @fredgoodman yes, that is correct

Comment: In (1) there are infinitely many primes $\equiv1\pmod4$ but that is a harder result than proving directly there are infinitely many S-primes.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of an $S$-prime is a number in $S$ that can not be written as a non-trivial product in $S$.

It is clear that a prime that is in $S$ is an $S$-prime, and there are infinitely many of these by a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof).

Every odd prime is congruent to $\pm 1$ mod 4.  The product of two primes each congruent to $-1$ mod 4 is an $S$-prime.  Any element of $S$ is the product of some number of primes in $S$  and some even number of primes congruent to $-1$ mod 4.  Hence it is the product of finitely many $S$-primes.  But if it has more than 2 (i.e. $2k$ for $k >1$) prime factors congruent to $-1$ mod 4, then these can be grouped in pairs in various ways, so the $S$-prime factorization is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

For (3), consider $ 21 \cdot 21 = 9 \cdot 49$.