# Question about proving there are infinitely many primes of the form 4n+1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

[Infinitely number of primes in the form $4n+1$ proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof#)

I saw this answer which says
Suppose n>1 is an integer. We define N=(n!)^2+1. Suppose p is the smallest prime divisor of N. Since N is odd, p cannot be equal to 2. It is clear that p is bigger than n (otherwise p∣1). "If we show that p is of the form 4k+1 then we can repeat the procedure replacing n with p and we produce an infinite sequence of primes of the form 4k+1."

I dont get how that last sentence makes sense. if p replaces n, then N=(p!)^2+1, then we can always find another smallest prime p' of N such that p'=4t+1? (so I thought the author meant N would be prime, but I guess not)

Comment: The proof does not state that $N$ is prime, just that the smallest prime divisor of $N$ is of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: If $n>1$ then $every$ prime divisor of $N$ is of the form $4k+1$ and is greater than $n.$

Answer (score 1):

The author just said “we can repeat the procedure”, but did not say that $N$ would then be prime. If we repeat the procedure, we get a prime $p'\neq p$. And if we repeat it again, we get a prime $p''$ such that $p''\neq p'$ and $p''\neq p$. And so on…

Comment: Each is shown to be larger than the previous, so there will not be any repeats and it produces an infinite sequence of these primes.

Comment: so once we find smallest prime p of N, we can place back p in place of n. But how would that gurantee there is a smallest prime p' of N? N=((4k+1)!)^2+1 always has prime p' such that it has a form 4t+1?

Comment: ohh since p was arbitrary, and I found that p is in the form 4k+1, I can do so for another bigger number! thx!

Comment: @SamuelKim If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: how do I do that? there is no button

Comment: Yes, there is. It is the ✓ sign below the downvote arrow.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that there are infinitely many such $p$. This can be expressed as:

> For all $n\in\Bbb N$, there exists such a $p$ with $p>n$.

As explained, working with $N=(n!)^2+1$ in the proof guarantees $p>n$.

Comment: & we don't need to consider the $least$ prime divisor of $N.$ If $n>1$ then any prime divisor of $N$ is greater than $n$ and is $\equiv 1\mod 4.$

Comment: Corollary: There is no largest prime. ;)