# Infinitude of prime in the arithmetic progression$4n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

[image]Is to possible to prove the problem with elementary approach as used to prove the case $4n+3$. Most of the proof that proves Infinitude of primes of the form $4n+1$ uses the some theorem from quadratic reciprocity.

So I was curious to know whether this proof can also be done as the same way as of the proof for the case $4n+1$ without using any special result.

I am aware of the proof of this fact available in this site. But I just want the proof in the way this book mentioned.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What goes wrong when you just follow the suggested method?  It's practically a complete solution...

Comment: Product of numbers of the form$4n+3$ can be of the form$4n+1$

Comment: I meant, the method suggested by the problem you quote.  All you need to note is that $-1$ can't be a square $\pmod p$ if $p=4k+3$.  That's a very basic point, nothing nearly as hard as Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: Can you explain it little more?

Comment: What I wrote is essentially equivalent to the accepted solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244915/infinitely-number-of-primes-in-the-form-4n1-proof), you just need to modify it (in a minor way) to fit the exact form in the suggestion.

Comment: But how do you prove the fact you just mentioned above

Comment: Please study the accepted answer in the duplicate I linked to.  That answer covers that point.  Or you could try to prove it yourself as an (elementary) exercise.  Just use Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: But here the integer is not if the form $n^2 +1$ rather it is of the form $n^2 +4$ . So how does it apply in this case?

Comment: Please think about it for a second.  I think you can sort these details out by yourself with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be the one highlighted above. The main tool you use to show the infinitude of primes of the form $4n+3$ is the fact that if a number $x$ satisfies:
$$x \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$$
then there exists a prime divisor which is $3 \bmod{4}$. This isn't true when you replace $3 \bmod{4}$ by $1 \bmod{4}$.

Thus, we have to use the first supplement of quadratic reciprocity to prove the infinitude of primes which are $1 \bmod{4}$. This is one of the simplest ways we can prove the same.

Comment: But the way writer presented the idea of the proof forced me to think it might be done more elementarily. I know the method used in the case $4n+3$ case wouldn't work here. But I was thinking whether any other elementary method would work.

Comment: @mathisfun The only reason why the $4n+3$ case was so elementary was because you could apply that manipulation. The idea of getting a contradiction is based on construction. The whole motivation behind construction is the property you are using. For the $4n+3$ case, we used the fact above. For the $4n+1$ case, the most elementary special property that distinguishes primes of this form from primes of the form $4n+3$ is the first supplement of quadratic reciprocity. Besides, if there was an easier solution, it would have definitely been found and would be popular by now.